# JavaScript handling multiple filter conditions

Tags: javascript, json, design-patterns

I have a big JSON information and some query strings are passed to filter that JOSN data. For example 
dept=eng&date=2019-11-26&passport=true. It need not be in any particular order. It can be by dept and then by date and then by passport, or only date or dept and then passport, or any possible combination.

Now, I am not asking for how to write filtering logic, but I want to know what is the best way to handle such combinations in code.

What I can think of is

```
if(dept){
  result = {// do something}
  if( date) {
    result = { //do something more(result }
  }
}
if(date) {
  result = { // do something }
 // handle all combinations
}

// more if conditions
```

I am pretty sure this is not the best approach.
Again I am  not asking how to write all this filter logic but want to know what is the best way or pattern to handle such permutations and combinations of filtering.

Comment: You shouldn't worry about the queryString parameters nor their order. The right approach is that this data should be filtered on the backend side.

Comment: Yes. I want to filter it on the backend side using Node. I get all the filter conditions from the query string from the client and I have to filter the data on Node and send back the response.